# Rhema versus Logos

Tags: word-study, john

What is the difference between ‘rhema’ and ‘Logos’? Does the difference between these two words provide deeper understanding to the mystery of ‘the Word was made flesh (John 1:14)’ and ‘God was manifest in the flesh (1 Timothy 3:16).’?

Comment: This is a good question and I have up-voted it. But one thing may not be immediately clear. The word ρημα _rhema_ 'word' does not occur i I Timothy 3:16.You are asking for the difference in meanings of ρημα, _rhema_ and  λογοσ, _logos_, both of which are usually translated 'word' in English bibles, such as the KJV.

Comment: [Rhema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhema) means (spoken) *word*, whereas [logos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos) includes *thought* (hence *logic*).

Comment: Rhema is not just the spoken word, but any means by which the Logos (the substance of what is being communicated) is conveyed. Written text, spoken text, text in Hebrew, Greek, English, etc are Rhema. Logos is discerned from Rhema.

Comment: Yes.  Expression only versus thought from which expression springs.

Comment: That makes good sense to me. (@Lucian  @enegue and @Mike) It seems to me that the confusion arises due to (presumably) well intentioned  efforts to Christianize secular words, and make too much of them.  Context should be more important.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following explains it pretty good.

> What Is a “Rhema”?
>
> Scripture for personal application
>
> Logos—The Word of God
>
> There are two primary Greek words that describe Scripture which are
>   translated word in the New Testament. The first, logos, refers
>   principally to the total inspired Word of God and to Jesus, Who is the
>   living Logos.
>
> Biblical Examples of Logos
>
> The following passages of Scripture give examples of the logos of God:
>   •“In the beginning was the Word [logos], and the Word [logos] was with
>   God, and the Word [logos] was God” (John 1:1).  •“The seed is the word
>   [logos] of God” (Luke 8:11).  •“Holding forth the word [logos] of
>   life” (Philippians 2:16).  •“Study to show thyself approved unto God,
>   a workman that needeth not to be ashamed, rightly dividing the word
>   [logos] of truth” (II Timothy 2:15).  •“For the word [logos] of God is
>   quick, and powerful” (Hebrews 4:12).  •“Being born again, not of
>   corruptible seed, but of incorruptible, by the word [logos] of God,
>   which liveth and abideth forever” (I Peter 1:23).
>
> Rhema—The Spoken Word
>
> The second primary Greek word that describes Scripture is rhema, which
>   refers to a word that is spoken and means “an utterance.” A rhema is a
>   verse or portion of Scripture that the Holy Spirit brings to our
>   attention with application to a current situation or need for
>   direction.
>
> Every word of God is inspired, and “all scripture is given by
>   inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for
>   correction, for instruction in righteousness” (II Timothy 3:16). It is
>   the Holy Spirit Who illuminates particular Scriptures for application
>   in a daily walk with the Lord.

The above is taken from the following site: https://iblp.org/questions/what-rhema I also don't think the difference relfects a deeper or a "mystery" type of understanding. The two words have different definitions and I don't want to "read" anything into what they mean because their meaning is pretty straight forward as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score -3):

Whether there is a difference between rhema and logos as the "*spoken word*" or "*thought*" of a person cannot inform our view of **John 1:1/14** because of the Greek syntax in which it is found.

At **John 1:1** we have ην **προς** τον θεον.

Look at this preposition chart:

[image]
￼

At 10:00 we have προς with an arrow facing the circle. It represents the word/Word facing and potentially moving towards God.

If it represented a word spoken by God or a thought of God it would be coming from God towards someone else.

Greek 101 prohibits the view that λόγος at **John 1:1** is God's spoken word or his own thoughts.   It's represented as facing him as from another person.

Comment: Why do all translations say "with God" if the only possible meaning is "facing/towards God"?